# anyone know how to pass 6Dof sensor data in Avtarposer?

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr, openvr

I want to generate Pose From AVATARPOSER [link](https://github.com/eth-siplab/AvatarPoser)
I HAVE VALVE INDEX SENSOR INPUT like below
single frame data of Sensor 6dof

```
head[0:2] = [ 4-0.0215,  1.6839,   -0.3118] , 
head_rotations_degrees[3:6] = [ 12.256 , -29.1672  ,  4.1962 ]  ,
head_Quaterion[7:9] =[0.9606 ,0.0941 ,-0.254,  0.0621]

lhand[10:12] =[-0.2894 , 0.7954 , -0.4965  ]   ,   
lhand_rotations_degrees[13:15] = [-25.667 ,  -9.3901, -27.3906] , 
lhand_Quaterion[16:19] =[0.9398   ,-0.1962 ,-0.13 ,  -0.2477]

rhand[20:22] =[ 0.2304 , 1.5386 ,  -0.5496  ]   ,  
rhand_rotations_degrees[23:25] = [72.1382 , -34.3834  ,  2.9661] , 
rhand_Quaterion[26:29] =[0.7674 ,   0.5561 , -0.2534, 0.1939]
```

> i m trying to generate 6d Pose of human body by passing head and hands input.

> i am trying to find how they take a input of head and hands data from amass dataset and generate full-body 6d pose.
> here

```
body_parms = {
                'root_orient': torch.Tensor(bdata_poses[:, :3]),#.to(comp_device), # controls the global root orientation
                'pose_body': torch.Tensor(bdata_poses[:, 3:66]),#.to(comp_device), # controls the body
                'trans': torch.Tensor(bdata_trans),#.to(comp_device), # controls the global body position
            }
```

i m trying to find head and hands 6dof data from this body param and pass VR headset 6dof sensor data in body_param